# I'm learning to program, and I wanted to know if there's any way to get this code to only accept whole numbers

Tags: c++

I wanted to know if there's any way to get this code to only accept whole numbers, and if you enter a number with decimals that of an error this is the code:

```
      if (anio % 4 == 0) {
        std::cout << "El anio "<<anio<<" es un anio biciesto" << '\n';
        return 0;
      }
      else if (anio % 100 == 0) {
        std::cout << "El anio "<<anio<<" no es un anio biciesto" << '\n';
        return 0;
      }
      else if (anio % 100 == 0 && anio % 400 == 0) {
        std::cout << "El anio "<<anio<<" es un anio biciesto" << '\n';
        return 0;
      }
      else{
        std::cout << "El anio "<<anio<<" no es un anio biciesto" << '\n';
        return 0;
      }
    }
    std::cout << "El anio que digito no es valido para el programa, debe ser un digito menor o igual a 500" << '\n';
    std::cout << "Quiere digitar otro anio? Digite 1 para volver a intentar o digite cualquier numero para salir del programa" << '\n';
    std::cin >> opcion;
    system("cls");
  } while(opcion==1);
  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can pre-flight the entered string to ensure it contains only digit characters, and if it doesn't then output an error message and prompt to retry input.

Comment: How do you read the input currently? Please try to create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to show it to us.

Comment: current entry supports years like this 2012.2 but I want it to only support 2012

Comment: @TonyK The year 1900 wasn't a leap year. Years divisible by 100 are not leap years unless they're also divisible by 400. (This is the difference between the Gregorian and Julian calendars).

Comment: Your code as it stands thinks that year 1900 is a leap year! And once you have fixed that, it will think that year 2000 is not a leap year. Can you see why?

Comment: @Ray: Sorry, typo. I have re-posted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `anio` a `float` and use [`std::modf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf) to detect whether it's a whole number.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float anio;

    std::cin >> anio;

    if (std::modf(anio, &anio) != 0f)
        throw std::invalid_argument("El año debe ser un número entero");

    // do stuff
}
```